# Python reading file into 2d list - newline=None vs strip("\r\n")

Tags: python, windows, newline

EDIT: bigbounty asked for sample data. I'm not sure how to keep the newlines when pasting here, so I've provided an image instead. See below.

I'm trying to determine the correct and most Pythonic way to strip newlines when reading data from an eternal file into a 2d list. I'm having trouble working out what `newline` does within `open()` (and yes, I have checked the docs - it still hasn't clicked for me). Is the code below the correct way to read data into a 2d list, avoiding capturing new line characters? Is any part of it redundant (e.g. `newline=None`?)

EDIT: I'm on windows, but looking for a cross-platform solution.

```
with open(file_name, "r", newline=None) as fh:
    list_2d = [[char for char in line.strip("\r\n")] for line in fh]
```

[image]

Comment: http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/06/readlines-considered-silly.html

Comment: Line terminators come in different 'flavours' for historical reasons, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline. `newline=None` (which is the default) means the different line terminators in the input will be replaced, standardized if you will, by `\n`. This helps makes your logic work on a larger range of input files.

Comment: Can you post sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `newline` argument to `open` enables [universal newline mode](https://docs.python.org/3.8/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines) if it is `None` or `''`. The difference between these two is that `None` also translates the newline characters to `\n` when the file is read (and translates them back if the file is written), whilst `''` doesn't perform this translation.

So if you use `open` with `newline=None`, you can expect any line ending in the file to be returned to you as `\n`, whichever platform you are on.

Since `newline=None` is the default (similarly, read for text mode is the default) your example can be written for any platform as:

```
with open(file_name) as fh:
    list_2d = [[char for char in line.strip("\n")] for line in fh]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be compatible with all platforms, you can open w.r.t. `'rU'` mode which opens your file in [Universal newline](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines) mode and then every newline occurrence will appear as a `'\n'` character (so then you only need to count `'\n'` chars). Since Python 3, [it is deprecated](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/298677/why-is-universal-newlines-mode-deprecated-in-python), the `'rU'` mode equals to `newline=None`, meaning that the code snippet is cross-platformatic.

```
list_2d = []
with open(file_name, newline=None) as fh:
     list_2d.append([x for x in line.split("\n")])
```

No need to use `'r'` specifier if you just wish to read because it is default argument already.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind reading the whole file into memory in one go (which, it seems, you don't mind doing, since you're consuming the entire file and stuffing it into a list), you could use `lines = file.read().splitlines()`, which would be a list of strings, where each string is one line (with no trailing carriage return or newline characters).

Answer (score 1):

Just don't put \n char in the list.

```
with open('a.txt', "r") as fh:
    list_2d = [[char for char in line if char!='\n'] for line in fh]
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to mention.

1. Read-only mode, that's default.
2. newLine = None, that's default.

```
with open(file_name) as fh:
    list_2d = [[char for char in line if char != "\n"] for line in fh]
```

Comment: Could you explain why this is sufficient, given the different line endings the program might encounter?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open When reading input from the stream, if newline is None, universal newlines mode is enabled. Lines in the input can end in '\n', '\r', or '\r\n', and these are translated into '\n' before being returned to the caller. And newline is None by default.